# About playing a video in a mobile

Tags: html

Can any one suggest me what is the tag used for displaying a video in mobile applications without using HTML5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/) does the job well. 
Try it it's free.